# How to generate allure report

Tags: maven, jasmine, protractor, allure

I am new to allure reports and want to generate the allure report. Can anyone help with this?

I am trying with a simple example, my project folder containing config.js and test.js and the allure report installed

when I run the config file it is creating a folder allure-results, in that I can see the screenshots and a xml file. I have no idea what to do from here, I am trying with maven but not able to generate the html report.

I have added the code of my example

config.js

```
exports.config = {
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
specs: 'test.js',

onPrepare: function () {
    var AllureReporter = require('jasmine-allure-reporter');
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new AllureReporter({
        allureReport: {
            resultsDir: 'allure-results'
        }
    }));
    jasmine.getEnv().afterEach(function (done) {
        browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (png) {
            allure.createAttachment('Screenshot', function () {
                return new Buffer(png, 'base64');
            }, 'image/png')();
            done();
        });
    });
}
};
```

test.js

```
describe('angularjs homepage todo list', function () {
var todoList = element.all(by.repeater('todo in todoList.todos'));

it('should add a todo', function () {
    browser.get('https://angularjs.org');

    element(by.model('todoList.todoText')).sendKeys('write first protractor test');
    element(by.css('[value="add"]')).click();
});

it('test 2', function () {
    expect(todoList.count()).toEqual(3);
});

it('test 3', function () {
    expect(todoList.get(2).getText()).toEqual('write first protractor test');
});

it('test 4', function () {
    // You wrote your first test, cross it off the list
    todoList.get(2).element(by.css('input')).click();
    var completedAmount = element.all(by.css('.done-true'));
    expect(completedAmount.count()).toEqual(2);
});
});
```

Comment: tried generating report via maven but it gave me an error saying Build failed, pom.xml file not found, from where can i get pom.xml for this project since I have only 2 files.?

Answer (score 18):

Direct Answer : By using `Allure Command Line Tool` you can generate report.

> when I run the config file it is creating a folder allure-results, in that I can see the screenshots and a xml file.

As you said, it is generating test result data and screenshot in that folder. You can generate report after this. Follow below steps.

1. Add this dependency by running `npm install allure-commandline --save-dev`
2. Run your tests and generate test result data (ie, after running it will generate `allure-results` folder).
3. From the same project directory run, `allure generate allure-results --clean -o allure-report` in the command prompt
4. On successfull execution it will generate one more folder `allure-report`in your directory.
5. Open `index.html` file in FireFox to show the report.

Note : If the report is in loading state, please try to open in different browsers

Comment: @suhail-ahmed are you able to generate report by this?

Comment: I am getting following error when I run the command.                                   
                               allure generate allure-results --clean -o allure-report
'allure' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: The report is generated by it displays loading loading everywhere

Comment: @AshokkumarGanesan Please open the `index.html` file in firefox

Comment: @jithinkmatthew i tried this the folder also is created but the issue here is when i open the index.html file i am getting everything blank, says loading. No graphs are displayed

Comment: and @jithinkmatthew when i use the above command it says --clean and -o does not exists

Comment: Anyone knows why when opened  index.hrml , report tabs are in loading state?

Answer (score 2):

If the allure report is available then the report can be viewed with the below command

```
allure generate 'available report folder path' && allure open
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution, an easy 1,

Allure setup in your system

1. Download allure latest version [downloadAllur][1]
2. extract the binary file
3. in System PATH variable add **allure->bin** path,
4. check whether allure is installed or not, in cmd prompt run **allure**

Step to generated allure report

1. run you test cases, allure-report folder with json files and screenshots is created
2. open cmd prompt
3. run following cmd in cmd prompt
   **allure serve path_of_allure-report_folder_generated**

The above command is used to only view the report

If we have generated the "allure-report" folder using the command

**allure generate path_of_allure-report_folder_generated --clean -o allure-report**

then there are chances that the index.html might not display any report due to browser constraints, so to open this index.html it is always good practice to open it from the command prompt using below command

**allure open path_of_'allure-report'_folder_generated**

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the `jasmine allure reporter` github

> In this method, we will use Maven. Copy ready-to-use pom.xml from
>   node_modules/jasmine-allure-reporter and run:
>
> mvn site -Dallure.results_pattern=allure-results
>
> It will put HTMLs into target/site/allure-maven-plugin folder. To
>   serve them via localhost:1324 use:
>
> mvn jetty:run -Djetty.port=1234

You can also use this one from one of my projects- [link](https://github.com/zac11/myswaastherp/blob/master/pom.xml), however check if the dependencies are correct - these are around 6+ months old.

Answer (score 0):

based on @jithinkmatthew answer, i used **Allure Command Line Tool**. After running your tests and allure-result folder is generated containing json or xml files. here is what worked for me,

1. Install Allure Command Line Tool globally. `npm install -g allure-commandline --save-dev`.
2. Run the following allure command to generate allure-report folder. `allure generate --single-file allure-results --clean -o allure-report`. This will generate allure-report folder containing single html file. The `--single-file` flag will generate single `index.html` **this is will avoid the loading state**.
3. You can open this `index.html` in any browser u want or u can send it by email if u want.

Answer (score 0):

1. open command prompt
2. CD to the location where you have the "allure-results" folder
3. run the command `allure serve --clean`