# Allure report not able to generate proper report showing unknown result

Tags: java, allure

Allure report opens but showing UNKNOWNE RESULT..

I tried to run JAVA code > allure folder was created > Inside that JSON files also created

> When I run code for generate allure report through cmd e.g allure serve followed_By_Link
> report opens but showing UNKNOWNE RESULT

Comment: For allure report to generate, you need to have all the required xml files in the same results folder.  ex: environments.xml   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50783032/how-to-generate-allure-report

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate allure report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50783032/how-to-generate-allure-report)